# How to limit for loop to print only first few records in list?

Tags: delphi

How should I print the first 5 element from list using for loop in Delphi. Below are the sample I created:

```
p := ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i'];
for P in p do begin
   showMessage(P);
end
```

By using this I was able to print all element in the list, but I wanted to print only the first 5. Please help if you know the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using `for .. in` when you don't want to iterate all of them? Use a standard for i := 0 to 4 do` loop instead. Also, those are not *records in a list* - they're elements in an array.

Comment: @KenWhite ohh ok i thought there are some way to limit in (for .. in) method. Thanks you for the info, i updated my question mistake.

Comment: No. `for .. in` means *for each item in*, not *for a few items in*. As I said, a normal `for` loop is appropriate if you only want some of the content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code below will do. It make use of an index variable looping from 0 (the first element of an array) to 4 (To get the first 5 elements).

```
var
  I : Integer;
begin
  var p := ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i'];
  for I := 0 to 4 do
      ShowMessage(p[I]);
end;
```

In other context, since array bounds are not limited to start at 0, and to avoid going out of range, you could use the functions Low(), High() and Min() like this:

```
for I := Low(p) to Min(Low(p) + 4, High(p)) do  // 5 items at most
    ShowMessage(p[I]);
```

To use `Min()` you must add `System.Math` to the uses clause.

Answer (score 1):

In order to keep the `for .. in` method, you could use a counter variable:

```pascal
var
  Count : Integer;
begin
  p := ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i'];
  Count := 0;
  for P in p do
    begin
      if Count < 5 then
        begin
          ShowMessage(P);
          Inc(Count);
        end;
    end;
end;
```

Or, more elegantly, use a standard `for index` loop:

```pascal
var
  I : Integer;
begin
  p := ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i'];
  for I := 0 to High(p) do
    begin
      if I < 5 then
        ShowMessage(p[I]);
    end;
end;
```

Comment: Why would you need the extra code in your standard loop example, instead of just `for i := 0 to 4`?

Comment: @KenWhite: Perhaps to make sure you don't get an index error, if the array only contains 3 elements? That, of course, could also be implemented as "to min(high(p),4)" (and he should use low(p) now that he uses high(p) to be consistent).

Comment: @Heartware: The question asks specifically how to get 5 elements. Even if the array had fewer, it asks for a specific number. If the array has fewer than that, then an exception should be raised, either before the loop is ever executed or when the array bounds are exceeded.

Comment: I agree with KenWhite. Looping through entire array and using IF clause inside loop to control how many elements are shown is terrible practice as you end up reading every item in a loop whether you show it or not. If for some reason there is no other way than to use IF clause to determine which items are shown you should at least use `Break` to exit loop when you iterated through all needed items.

Comment: @Heart `for i := 0 to Min(5, N) - 1` do is the pattern

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I disagree. The (to me) correct pattern is _for I := Low(p) to Min(Low(p) + 4, High(p)) do_  this will always give you (up to) the five first entries of the array "p".

Comment: @heart variants on a theme, the point being that the indexed for loop is clearer than the for in loop for this

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Not quite. Your example assumes that the lower limit is 0, which may not be the case (in a general sense). My example works regardless of the lower limit of the array. I always prefer to use a generic solution to a problem instead of one that has built-in assumptions - especially when the resulting compilation is identical (which I believe it'll be in this case - maybe mine will even be shorter than yours)...

Comment: @heart I understand that. My point is about indexed for loop vs for in. I'm very happy to use `Low()`.

Comment: I completely agree with @SilverWarior: If you absolutely must use a `for in` instead of a simple `for` (the latter being the right thing to do), at least you should `Break` when you are done. Such a waste of CPU cycles to do 1M iterations to print the five first elements of an array!